# What is the difference between "<Value>0</Value>" and "<Value xsi:type="xsd:string">0</Value>"?

Tags: xml, parsing, xsd, xml-parsing

I'm a test analyst and my remote management activity works when the value is passed as `<Value xsi:type="xsd:string">0</Value>` but it doesn't work when the value is passed as  `<Value>0</Value>`.

I would like to understand why and my knowledge in XML is not that good.

Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `xsi:type="xsd:string"` construct conveys data type information in the absence of a schema. The application that processes the XML document can use this information to treat the content of the `<Value>` element as a string, and not as a number, even if it looks like one.